# What does "Yielding up his Spirit" mean?

Tags: john, jesus, spirit

Joh 19:30 BSB

> When Jesus had received the sour wine, He said, “It is finished.” And bowing His head, He yielded up His spirit.

If Jesus Yielded his spirit to God

Does this mean he stayed dead for the 3 days?

And that it is his Spirit that God gave back to him on the 3rd day?

Answer (score 2):

If Jesus Yielded his spirit to God
Does this mean he stayed dead for the 3 days
And that it is his Spirit that God gave back to him on the 3rd day?

The answer to your question is yes he stayed dead for three days And God gave his spirit back on day three.

Jesus came in the likeness of Adam. In order to overcome the curse he has to participate in it, which is death.

> because of the suffering of death, having been crowned with glory and with honor, so that by the grace of God He might taste death for everyone.
> Heb: 9<

Death as described in scripture.

Body returns to soil.

> For soil you are, And two soil you shall return. Genesis 3:19<

The spirit returns to God.

> Luke 23:46 Jesus commits his spirit to God.<

> Ecclesiastes 12:7
> Spirit returns to God who gave
> it.<

The soul becomes nonexistent since it is a combination of the spirit and body together to make it a living soul.

Adam became a living soul when the Spirit of God was breathed into his body.

> And the LORD God formed man of the dust of the ground, and breathed into his nostrils the breath of life; and man became a living soul. Genesis 2:7<

Jesus died and knew nothing during that time of death.

> Ecclesiastes 9:5 The dead no nothing.<

That is how scripture defines death.

Jesus did not exist then… He was dead. Just like Adam.

> Job 14:14
> If a man dies will he live again.<

When God put his spirit back into Jesus body he returned.

God raised him out of the dead.

> And you killed the Author of life, whom God has raised up out from the dead, whereof we are witnesses.  Acts 3:15<

It was on the third day God raised up Christ.

> God raised Him up on the third day and caused Him to be seen—acts 10:49<

He's the only one that has immortality right now

> 1 Timothy 6:12:16
> Who alone has immortality?
> This is for spoken after Jesus died so no one has immortality yet.<

There are different resurrections as stated 1:Corinthians 15:20-23

The Order of Resurrection

> Christ has indeed been raised from the dead, the firstfruits of those who have fallen asleep. For since death came through a man, the resurrection of the dead comes also through a man. For as in Adam all die, so in Christ all will be made alive. But each in his own turn: Christ the firstfruits; then at His coming, those who belong to Him.<

The last enemy of God that will be destroyed is death.

> For since death came by a man, so also by a man has come the resurrection of the dead. For as indeed in Adam all die, so also in Christ all will be made alive.  1Corinthians 15:21<

> The  last enemy to be destroyed is death. 1 cor. 15:26<

> Where O Death, is your victory? 1 Corinthians 15:55<

Comment: While I'd love to +1 I'm puzzled by, "When God put his spirit back into Jesus body he returned". This sounds like he was raised with the same spirit as he died with.

Comment: Steve,  Great question! It had to of been God Spirit  that raised him up of course Out of the dead.  That showed that He accepted Christ faith that was perfect.  So he raised him from the dead.  Gave him back his spirit as well at the same time I would assume.

Comment: Hmmm, we went from a mortal man with a spirit like us, to an immortal man, so it can't have been just getting *his* spirit back.

Comment: It was his body in the flesh that became a sin offering where sin was condemned in his body.  It was at that time he died.
Hebrews 2:14
Now since the children have flesh and blood, He too shared in their humanity, so that by His death He might destroy him who holds the power of death, that is, the devil,
God sending his own Son in the likeness of sinful flesh, and for sin, condemned sin in the flesh:
6For as the Father has life in Himself, so also He has granted the Son to have life in Himself. 
John 6:57
No one takes it from Me, but I lay it down of My own accord.

Answer (score 1):

That would depend on what you understood his spirit to be. Some religious groups say it was merely "the breath of life" that has to keep going in and out of the lungs for physical life to continue. The implication of such an idea is that Jesus breathed out his last lungful of air and then deliberately refused to take in more air.

However, if the biblical view of "the spirit in man" (Job 32:8) is examined, then another meaning is obtained (which does not deny the need for air in and out of the lungs). In Ecclesiastes chapter 12 we read of old age and death creeping over a person, till the very point of physical death, when "the dust shall return to the earth as it was: and the spirit shall return unto God who gave it" (vs. 7). The living are admonished to fear God from the days of their youth onward because after the spirit returns to God who gave it, he judges the works of the person.

The parallel account of Jesus' death in Luke's gospel states that with the supernatural darkness and rending of the temple curtain from top to bottom at the 6th hour:

> "And when Jesus had cried with a loud voice, he said, 'Father, into
> thy hands I commend my spirit: and having said thus, he gave up the
> ghost" (Luke 23:44-46)

Notice the link with Stephen being stoned to death later on - Stephen had exclaimed at seeing a vision of the resurrected Christ standing at the right hand of God in heaven. That was when the stoning started. At the last, Stephen called upon God and said, "Lord Jesus, receive my spirit". He also asked the Lord not to charge his murderers with that sin, further echoing more of Jesus' words from the cross. Then he died. Read Acts 7:54-60.

Neither Jesus nor Stephen were committing their last exhalation of air from their lungs to God. No, they knew there was an invisible, spiritually aware spirit in them that they entrusted back to God, in confidence of living on in the spirit, though their physical bodies died.

***To answer your question:*** Jesus' physical body died after he'd committed his invisible spirit to God, but he remained spiritually alive and aware. Jesus' corpse was resurrected as a glorified body, fit for being on earth and ascending into heaven. Stephen's corpse will yet be resurrected on the Day of Resurrection and Judgment. But Stephen is spiritually alive, awaiting that glorious reunion with a glorified body.

Comment: Nice Answer.  By "spiritually Alive" you mean.  Soul Consciousness?

Comment: on what passage do you fond support for "living on in the spirit, though their physical bodies died." Or," but he remained spiritually alive and aware"?

Answer (score 1):

Luke 23:

> 46
> Jesus called out with a loud voice, “Father, into your hands I commit my **spirit**.” When he had said this, he breathed his last.

What does "Yeilding up his Spirit" mean?

The spirit is a real entity that exists in the spiritual realm. At this time, by Jesus' command, his spirit left his physical body.

If Jesus Yielded his spirit to God
Does this mean he stayed dead for the 3 days?

His physical body stayed dead.

And that it is his Spirit that God gave back to him on the 3rd day?

His spirit reunited with his physical body at this time.

Comment: So when Stephen died he yeilded his Spirit to God and his body was buried where was his soul(person) ?

Comment: Where in the Bible that says Stephen yielded his Spirit?

Comment: While they were stoning him, Stephen appealed, “Lord Jesus, receive my spirit.”

Comment: That's not "yielded"? I try to stick close to the original wording as much as possible :)

Answer (score 1):

When Jesus died he surrendered his spirit - his mortal human spirit, back to his Father and God. John 20:17

The NT explicitly says Jesus was a man - still is. By his own words, Jesus says,

> you seek to kill me, a m-a-n who has told you the truth that I heard from G-o-d. John 8:40

> there is one God and one mediator between God and mankind, the man Christ Jesus. 1Tim 2:5

So Jesus is still a man and no one inspired by God has shown him to be otherwise even given *plenty of opportunity* to impart another truth on this important matter. if there was some extra truth to impart about who Jesus is - the NT does not provide it. The Gospels provide ample evidence of who he is.

> having been put to death indeed in the flesh, but having been made alive in the spirit 1 Pet 3:18

> knowing that Christ, having been raised from the dead, is never to die again; death no longer is master over Him. Rom 6:9

While in the physical state of flesh - being born of a mother, just as we all are, Jesus was subject to death - it was master over him, he was subjected to it as a man.

> Death no longer *rules over Him* BLB

So when he died, he was dead for the 3 days and nights as required. Matt 12:40

No one ascends to heaven or anywhere else, when anyone dies they go to 'sleep' and wait for the resurrection.

> No one has ever gone into heaven except the one who came from heaven John 3:13

When Jesus was raised he became immortal and had spirit life he didn't before. He said he wasn't a spirit - God is a spirit and angels are spirits, but Jesus is a man - made like us - he is not a spirit, saying so himself to make sure we get it!

> Touch me, and see. For a spirit does not have flesh and bones as you see that I have. Luke 24:39

Jesus did not receive his old spirit back - he received a new spirit of life - so that he could not die anymore. With his previous spirit, like us, we too can die until we are given the new spirit at our resurrection and we become immortal too.

He was a forerunner for us, a first fruit of all his brethren. Heb 6:20 1Cor 15 He goes before us in exactly the same way we will go.

Jesus, the man, yielded up his spirit as death was imminent. He had no control over his life or his death - just as we don't. But he did express some important truths as he was dying so we could understand more about who he was and what he had accomplished for us.

> And Jesus called out with a loud voice, “Father, into your hands I entrust my spirit. ” Saying this, he breathed his last.

Jesus is specifically reinforcing the truth that he was a man like us - there is no 'eternal Son of God' that his sprit goes back to, nor back to the Holy Spirit either, but back to his Father who provided it in the first place - just as He does for all men. The erroneous idea that only Jesus' body died is unbiblical and is a mockery of Jesus' life and sacrifice for sin.

++++++++++++++

The bible speaks of *sleep*, referring to death. This is the first death that all men will die. While we 'sleep' we know nothing nor are conscious in any way. After the resurrections, there will be a second death Rev 20, that will erase those who have not accepted the terms of their forgiveness in Christ. They will not sleep or have life ever again - they will cease to exist.

Answer (score 0):

It simply means that He expired, or died: "I am the First and the Last, even He that liveth. **And I became dead:** and behold I live for ever" (Revelation 1:17). Death is not, after all, any kind of end or destruction, except as regards the body: and Jesus' body was not allowed to corrupt according to the natural course, since it was raised prematurely (before the General Resurrection at the end of time):

> **Acts 13:35-37** And therefore, in another place also, he saith: **Thou shalt not suffer thy holy one to see corruption.** For David, when he had served in his generation, according to the will of God, slept: and was laid unto his fathers, and saw corruption. **But he whom God hath raised from the dead, saw no corruption.**

"To yield" or "give up" the spirit simply means to 'let go of it,' and free it, as it were, from the body. After all, to live means to be with your spirit, and to lack that spirit, means to be a dead body. And when all humans die (Jesus was a true descendant of Adam, and the New Adam), their souls depart from their body for the place of the souls of the departed: Sheol (or, at least, before the New Covenant when Christ opened Heaven). This is why, when Jesus arose three days later, He is said to have rose "from the dead" which in Greek is plural and refers to rising from "[the place of] the [souls of the] dead [ones]" and not from the state of being "dead" ("re-surrection" / "rising-again" refers to that). Hence also St. Paul:

> **Ephesians 4:8** Wherefore he saith: Ascending on high, he led **captivity** captive; he gave gifts to men. 9 Now that he ascended, what is it, but because **he also descended first into the lower parts of the earth?**

Cf. Philippians 2:10.

St. Peter writes about the same thing:

> For Christ also died once for our sins, the righteous for the unrighteous: that he might offer us to God, being put to death indeed **in the flesh,** but enlivened **in the spirit,** **in which also coming he preached to those spirits that were in prison:**

When you died before Christ came, Heaven was not open, you simply went to the place of the dead, Sheol, waiting. If you were a good person, who had an implicit or explicit hope in Christ, you went to a happy place therein with the Fathers, which Jesus called "Abraham's Bosom" (Luke 16:22). Otherwise you went to a kind of hell or, alternatively, purgatorial (it's not absolutely clear) place spoken of in the same passage (16:23).

Christ, likewise, went to the abode of the dead, yet not to be kept there in a "prison," as St. Peter calls it (since Heaven was closed since the Fall of Adam, you could only be kept in a 'holding place' awaiting Christ), but to release them, and, as St. Paul says, "lead captivity captive." When He "rose again," his spirit reentered His body, which is what makes a corpse, well, not a corpse: an alive human being, it was the same "spirit" He "gave up."

("Ghost" and "spirit" are simply the German and Latin words for, well, spirit. They don't refer to different things.)

Comment: Interesting.  Perspective